# Replacing old dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

[image]

I am trying to replace a dimmer switch. It appears to have been set up as a three way, but we can’t find a second switch that would control the light.

It seems that all the wires coming out of the old dimmer switch end up connecting to a different black wire from the wall. And naturally, the ground isn’t connected.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Keep looking for that switch... behind a blank cover where it might have been removed or in another room, end on hallway, etc.

Comment: Yes -- we'll need to find that other switch in order to crack this, because something weird's going on here for sure

Comment: There are no red wires, so something janky may be going on.

Comment: I’ve checked every switch on the first floor. There is no other switch that turns the light off that the dimmer controls